# sqlite saving text file and output as it is : python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to save a text file in sqlite using python but when I try to retrieve the file, I see newline character and other characters. Is there any way to output the file as it is like the original file? Is there any work around.

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c=conn.cursor()

c.execute("create table code_tag1 (language text, code BLOB, tag text)")
#c.execute("select * from sqlite_master")
with open("bubblesort_java.txt","rb") as f:
    ablob=f.read()

c.execute("insert into code_tag1 values('java',?,'bubblesort')",[buffer(ablob)])
conn.commit()
row=c.execute("select * from code_tag1").fetchone()
print (repr(str(row[1])))
conn.close()
```

The output is :

```
'import java.util.Scanner;\r\n \r\nclass BubbleSort {\r\n  public static void main(String []args)     
{\r\n    int n, c, d, swap;\r\n    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);\r\n \r\n     
System.out.println("Input number of integers to sort");\r\n    n = in.nextInt();\r\n \r\n    int 
array[] = new int[n];\r\n \r\n    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " integers");\r\n \r\n    for 
(c = 0; c < n; c++) \r\n      array[c] = in.nextInt();\r\n \r\n    for (c = 0; c < ( n - 1 ); 
c++) {\r\n      for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++) {\r\n        if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For 
descending order use < */\r\n        {\r\n          swap       = array[d];\r\n          array[d]   
= array[d+1];\r\n          array[d+1] = swap;\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n \r\n    
System.out.println("Sorted list of numbers");\r\n \r\n    for (c = 0; c < n; c++) \r\n      
System.out.println(array[c]);\r\n  }\r\n}'
```

How can I get the code as it is in original file?

Thanks

Abhinav

Comment: Have you tried removing the repr() on the print line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the output. You're printing the `repr` of the string, which is why it shows the `\r`, `\n`, etc.

```
>>> data = """Hello
... World"""
>>> 
>>> print data
Hello
World
>>> print repr(data)
'Hello\nWorld'
>>>
```

Comment: thanks aneroid and rafael.. repr was the problem..I read it gives the object representation so included that.. now I got the actual meaning thanks.